# Корректна ли пунктуация в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

*А заявления перед толпой: "Так сделать было нужно", "Все равно к этому все шло" – точно не подействуют.*

Читаю [Розенталя](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/52.htm#%D0%B7_04), но все не разберусь. Или не то читаю?

Comment: Из того, что вы читаете, в этом разделе,  важно следующее: подлинные выражения, заключенные в кавычки, могут вставляться в текст в качестве элементов предложения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, ваше оформление верно. Здесь, полагаю, важно не то, что прямая речь внутри слов автора, а то, что две фразы в кавычках представляют собой перечисление. Поэтому и оформление должно быть по правилам перечисления: двоеточие до, тире после, запятая между ([Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=76#ppp_3)).

Comment: Не хватает только ссылки на Розенталя или ПАС,

Comment: @Sharon добавил. Я, кстати, задумался, что здесь будет обобщающим элементом. "Заявления" или всё сочетание "Заявления перед толпой"?

Comment: Заявление – обобщающее слово, перед толпой – несогласованное определение, которое к нему относится. Так что все сочетание.

Comment: В вашей  ссылке вроде бы ничего не говорится про прямую речь.

Comment: @Sharon а ещё мне кажется, что фразы в кавычках можно отбить с обеих сторон тире. То есть рассматривать как пояснительную конструкцию, поскольку они представляют собой два примера: *А заявления перед толпой – "Так сделать было нужно", "Все равно к этому все шло" – точно не подействуют*.

Comment: @Sharon в моей ссылке говорится про перечисление, поскольку я считаю, что здесь именно оно.

Comment: Нужно, чтобы Лопатин и Розенталь так же считали, как и вы (надо эту ссылку найти – "волшебные слова" для разрешения подобных действий).  А тире здесь меньше подходит, так как получается присоединительная конструкция. А для нас важны именно высказывания, поэтому надо ставить двоеточие с интонационном предупреждением. Тогда прямая речь становится более значимой

Comment: @Sharon да не прописываются в справочниках все частные случаи. Перечислительная интонация налицо, что ещё надо. Впрочем, я с интересом прочитаю ваш ответ, как только он будет опубликован.

Comment: А уже передумала ее публиковать, правильный ответ-то уже есть.  Наверное, и так сойдет.

Comment: @Sharon https://i.imgur.com/pTkzCiI.jpg

Comment: Очень милый мальчуган, мне понравился :)) Только не пойму, что он построил.  Хороша ссылка, все будут надеяться, что увидят нужную информацию

Comment: @Sharon это ж из советского мультика, "Вовка в Тридевятом царстве")

Comment: Да? Надо посмотреть! А вообще это символ современного образования. Диалог поздно вечером: – Ты уроки сделала, "Три толстяка» прочитала? – Нет пока.  – Да это большая книга, когда же ты успеешь?! – А я краткое содержание в Интернете прочитаю, и так сойдет! (4-й класс)

Comment: @Sharon образование-то тут при чём. Это личная лень. Халтура как образ жизни

Comment: У нас таких ленивых каждый первый. Детей приучают к халтуре именно в образовательной среде, так как методики их обучения безнадежно устарели.  А своими делами (тем, что им интересно) они занимаются охотно. Это дети другого информационного века и учить их нужно по-другому.

Comment: @Sharon спасибо, как человек, который учился в педуниверситете, я понимаю, насколько устарела система.

Comment: Nektoid, вы и Niemend один и тот же человек?

Comment: @Серж Конечно нет. Если вы не шутите и я всерьёз похож на этого удалённого с сайта утырка, то мне срочно надо менять своё поведение.

Comment: Стиль похож, поэтому спросил.